# Why did the Unicode Consortium add Supplementary Private Use Area B?

Tags: unicode

In 1996, Unicode 2.0 extended the Unicode range from code points U+0 through U+10FFFF, arranged in 17 "planes" numbered 0 through 16.  They did this because there wasn't enough space in 16 bits, so they bumped the limit out — not to exactly 20 bits, but to the very odd number of 20.0625 bits.  I've wondered for years — and hopefully somebody knows why — why did they add that *17th* plane, the "Supplementary Private Use Area B" plane?

I realize, of course, that when they went beyond 16 bits, they could have easily gone all the way up to 32.  And that 32-bit limit would have made sense, had they chosen it.  And if their goal was to be "big enough, but no bigger," then exactly 20 bits could have also made sense — ending at exactly U+FFFFF, which would have simplified coding for it a little.  But instead of ending there, Unicode goes up to that 20-bit mark, and then it adds another 64K of *additional* "private use area".  It almost seems like they went up to U+FFFFF and then some committee member insisted that one more private use area was really needed for some reason, even though planes 3-13 are unallocated and would have had plenty of space for whatever that purpose was.

So does anyone *actually* know why that counter-intuitive 17th plane was added back in the Unicode 2.0 days?

Comment: It's connected to the design of UTF-16, which can encode code points up to exactly U+10FFFF, but I don't have sources for what motivated what in the design process.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that the limit was purely motivated by technical limitations of the then-undefined UTF-16 encoding.  Maybe it was, but given how deliberate the Unicode Consortium is, I'd be really surprised if that's the answer.

Comment: The design of UTF-16 was a big influence on the design of the rest of Unicode. They had to give up 2048 code points from the BMP for surrogates. I don't think anyone even wanted a 20-bit encoding - with 2.5 bytes per code point, it would have been even more awkward than UTF-16. There's certainly no one clamoring for a UTF-21 or UTF-24.

Comment: Note that the surrogate mechanism was defined, and surrogate code points allocated, before the Unicode planes were even defined and before Supplementary Private Use Area B was a thing.